# Deforming each vertex according to the user in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I am trying to work on a project in OpenGL in which I want to make an animated complex-valued function plotter. Basically, I am trying to do the animation illustrated in the topmost image of this page:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function

This means that I will need to tranform each vertex of my complex plane, and the way I tranform each vertex depends on the given function. Morevoer, this function is user-defined and is not known to the program.

Now, initially I had thought of passing a function pointer to the vertex shader but I just learned that it cannot be done (Till now, I had only worked in OpenGL 2.0. This is my first Advanced OpenGL project). How else can I do it?

Comment: Two possibilities come to mind: 1) generate your vertex shader as text, injecting a string representing the function you want evaluated, and then compile this dynamically generated source code. 2) CPU-side, run the custom function to generate points which you store as pixels in a texture, and then read this information in your shader as a vertex texture. Neither these techniques nor this problem are unique to games though, so you might consider asking on a general [computer graphics site](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @DMGregory , thanks for the suggestions! I was working on the first possibility so far, but it's not very convenient as I lose out on the robustness of using std::complex functions.

As per your suggestion, I will flag this question for a moderator to move.